# What is application server in base image?

Tags: java, rest, http, containers, quarkus

In the [base image](https://quarkus.io/guides/quarkus-runtime-base-image), the command uses `-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0`. My Quarkus application uses Kafka and I don't see the need to expose a HTTP server. How do I not expose this HTTP end-point? Also, is this end-point tied to the `quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson` extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application does not expose an HTTP server, setting `quarkus.http.host` will have no effect.
More technically, this setting is used by the `quarkus-vertx-http` extension.

Furthermore, you can always override the docker `CMD` instruction if you want to.

Comment: Ok. But, if I use the `smallrye-health-check` extension, then this setting would be _required_ right?

Comment: `quarkus-smallrye-health` depends on `quarkus-vertx-http`